# How to convert asset-library:// to file:// in react-native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo to build a cross-platform application. In my app, I have a screen where user can select images or videos to upload.

When I use `expo-image-picker` to select image it gives me an object which its uri starts with `file:///` and I can use this uri to display the image.

When I use `expo-image-picker-multiple` to select multiple images it gives me objects and the uri starts with `asset-library://` and I can't use this uri to display the content of it nor send it to server.

How can I convert this `asset-library://` to `file://`? What keyword should I use to get better results when doing google search on this problem or which tool should I use? I can't really find a proper solution to this one. This occurs on IOS devices.

Thanks!

[EDIT]

here is my code

```
var assetUri = 'asset-library://....'
var tempDir = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.jpg`
FileSystem.copyAsync({
   from: assetUri,
   to: tempDir
})
try {
  var assetResult = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(tempDir, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8
  })
  console.log(assetResult)
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

File 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0E-FC42-4630-B3C7-537D5EFB7D1F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/ichardexpohong/gwmke.jpg' could not be read.

Comment: ever found a fix, i'm with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I wanted only the filename so i used

```
let filename= result.assets[0].uri.split('/')[result.assets[0].uri.split('/').length-1]
```

so maybe if the path after both asset-library and file://  are the same you can use
take away the asset-library:// then replace it with file://

```
let uri='file://' + object.uri.split('asset-library://')[1]
```

hope it helps